# Where to store the state of the selected item in gridview?

Tags: android, gridview, hashmap

I have gridview with imageview - for custom gallery image select. And i store the state of the selected item in image class

```
public int changeState ()
{
    if (State==0)
        State=1;
    else
        State=0;

    return State;
}
```

but i read this thing

> It's a bad idea to store the state checked in a business (model)
>   class. The view displaying the data should take care of it.

So where to store the state of the selected item? Some kind of `HashMap<Pic,State>`?

Comment: You should store this information in your gridView adapter. You can store the selected index.

Answer (score 0):

You can store any additional information in the view (`ImageView` or whatever) itself using `setTag(int, Object)`.

First, define an id in `res/values/ids.xml`

```
<item type="id" name="state" />
```

Then call `setTag`:

```
imageView.setTag(R.id.state, 1); // or whatever object you want to store.
```

Get it back using `getTag`:

```
imageView.getTag(R.id.state);
```

Comment: and how to select all objects with desired tag? where tag=1